# Is it possible to disable automatic line breaks on Sass's CSS output?

Tags: css, sass

I very frequently use the CSS line numbers in Inspect Element to find where a rule is in a particular CSS file. When Sass outputs a CSS file, it imposes its own style rules on it which really don't line up 1:1 with how my SCSS is formatted. This makes it hard to find CSS rules in my code because none of the line numbers match. It's completely disturbing my workflow and is a major barrier to my further adoption of Sass.

I've already looked at `sass --style=expanded` and `sass --style=compressed` but neither of them come anywhere close to matching the whitespace style I want.

What I really need is a way to make Dart leave all my whitespace and line breaks exactly as they are, and minify mixins down to a single line each. Something you might call `--style=preserve-line-numbers` Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No. That is not possible by SASS itself.**

If you like you may have a look to the avaiable styles:
https://sass-lang.com/documentation/js-api#outputstyle

But to be honest: if you use SASS in the intended way with nested styles, mixins, using modules ... the compiled CSS will considerably differ from the SASS code anyway. That even applys to the line numbers. So your problem is a common challenge in the coding process.

**As fast debugging is important** SASS offers mapping technique:

If activated you are able to see the source code in the browser on the fly. That's really easy and should meet your demands. Maybe you like to have a look on it. Here is a good overview to it: https://thesassway.com/using-source-maps-with-sass-3-3/

Or however if not that way there is **another little trick/workarround** which may help:

Most SASS projects organize/structures code in partial files (which doesn't make it possible to keep line numbers). That's for different reasons and speeds up working as well. If you do so you just start every file with a CSS comment which notes the file name only. As comments are shown in the browser tools you are able to find the relevant SASS source file without mapping ... and as partial files are almost not as long finding the relevant code (which differs from the CSS) should not longer be the problem.

```
// ### examples partial filename in a CSS comment

/* base-typography */
...

/* base-forms */
...

/* section-hero */
...
```

That is not as fast as mapping technique I would really recommend. But finding the code that way is faster than try to keep line numbers exactly the same and missing that way a lot of other advantages of SASS which speeds up my work (like nestings, setting SASS only comments, using mixins and modules ...).

Comment: Source maps are working for me perfectly, thank you! ([instructions to enable them in VS Web Compiler](https://github.com/madskristensen/WebCompiler#source-maps) )